# Angular4 HttpClient turning params into single characters

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I am creating an api call using HttpClient as follows:

```
let headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .append("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
    .append("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate")
    .append("Pragma", "no-cache")
    .append("Expires", "0");

let params = new HttpParams()
    .append("status", "O")
    .append("status", "D")
    .append("status", "B")
    .append("user", "true");

let requestOptions = { params: params, headers: headers };

return this.httpClient.get("api/Batch", requestOptions)
    .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
```

When I view this requestOptions object in the debugger, the params look fine, but in the network tab in chrome developer tools, for some reason the url looks like this:

> http://localhost:50347/_QDX/api/Batch?0=s&1=t&2=a&3=t&4=u&5=s&6==&7=O&8=%26&9=s&10=t&11=a&12=t&13=u&14=s&15==&16=D&17=%26&18=s&19=t&20=a&21=t&22=u&23=s&24==&25=B&26=%26&27=s&28=t&29=a&30=t&31=u&32=s&33==&34=O&35=%26&36=s&37=t&38=a&39=t&40=u&41=s&42==&43=D&44=%26&45=s&46=t&47=a&48=t&49=u&50=s&51==&52=B&53=%26&54=u&55=s&56=e&57=r&58==&59=t&60=r&61=u&62=e&63=%26&64=u&65=s&66=e&67=r&68==&69=t&70=r&71=u&72=e&73=%26&74=g&75=u&76=i&77=d&78==&79=7&80=6&81=a&82=d&83=d&84=3&85=2&86=0&87=d&88=a&89=e&90=1&91=4&92=c&93=0&94=f&95=a&96=2&97=b&98=0&99=6&100=c&101=b&102=e&103=a&104=8&105=1&106=3&107=4&108=7&109=0&110=b

I am clueless as to what is causing this. It is splitting each character from the params up and putting them in the querystring by position. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Seems to work fine for me (at least on Angular 6): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7qxq7o Are you using the built-in HttpClient or something on top of it? Do you have any interceptors that could do this?

Comment: So I was copying the parameters to a new HttpParams object and using .toString() to do some string manipulation while passing it in. The toString() was causing the issue.

Comment: @KevinDoyon thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: @KevinDoyon turns out I was doing a toString() on httpParams somewhere and that was causing this.

Comment: Glad you found your problem :) It might be hard if there's lot of stuff you don't necessarily want to post on stack overflow, but next time the actual code you run is useful to see (there was no `toString()` in your code sample, so I never would've been able to pinpoint the problem). Also in the future, it's useful to simplify your problematic code to its simplest form (like I did with the stackblitz) and add back some of the extra code you have (like the `toString()` call). Once you start seeing the problem again, it's whatever you just added to your simple code that causes problems.